# ROBLOX - Iterate through Frame buttons

Tags: lua, roblox

I seem to be unable to iterate through "name, child in pairs(game.StarterGui.AdminCmds.Commands:GetChildren()) " to change attributes on all child elements

I have a GUI Frame with a number of buttons. When a user clicks a button, (1) the code should reset the BackgroundColor3 of all buttons to default, then (2) toggle the BackgroundColor3 of the click button to highlight it.

Part 2 works fine, but part (1) fails to change the background colour, most likely due to how I am attempting to address the Frame children. If I do a "print (name, child)" during the operation, I can see the correct values, but the BackgroundColor3 fails to change.

```
local button = script.Parent
local toggled = false

local function onButtonActivated()
-- Loop through Frame and reset button colour
    for name, child in pairs(game.StarterGui.AdminCmds.Commands:GetChildren()) do
        child.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 85, 127)
    end

-- Update clicked button colour
    if toggled == false then
        button.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(85, 170, 255)
        toggled = true
    else
        button.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 85, 127)
        toggled = false
    end
end

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(onButtonActivated)

local button
local toggled
```

No errors, just no colour change. The localscript is attached to one of the buttons currently as a test. I intend to change it to a Module, but how to do that is a question for another day.

Answer (score 0):

Answer found through trial and error. The problem was that I was trying to reference the StartGUI, which is moved to PlayerGUI upon player start, which is wrong.

The For loop which runs through the Frame children where the button was clicked, should look like this:

```
for name, child in pairs(script.Parent.Parent:GetChildren()) do
    child.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.fromRGB(0, 85, 127)
end
```

So what I have discovered, is that you can traverse the tree regardless of where your object is by using .Parent as many times as required. Handy.